# Resource Allocation Graph Deadlock Detection

Tags: graph, operating-system, process

I know that a circular request would cause a deadlock, but I am wondering if the following would also cause a deadlock...

[image: Resource Graph]

I am unclear but I also thought that if "A failure or inability to proceeed due to two or more programs/processes both requiring a response from the other before completing an operation"

Would this mean that if both Process 2 and Process 4 need R7 this is going to cause a deadlock? (Same for resource R5 and R4 being requested by multiple processes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest deadlock graph, to use the notation in your picture, is when two process each require the same two resources. For example, if in your example process `P2` depended upon resource `R5`, there's possibility for deadlock. Suppose that both `P2` and `P4` each request both `R7` and `R5`, that `P2` locks `R7` and `P4` locks `R5`. Then `P2` is waiting for `R5` and `P4` is waiting for `R7`, that is, each is waiting for the other to release a lock. This is a minimal example.

In your situation, there's no such possibility, since no two resources are ever shared by the two different processes. The only one in question at all is `P4`. If there's contention with `P2` or `P7`, say, then either `P4` will execute first (no problem) or else the other process with execute first, unlock the resource, and allow `P4` to execute (also no problem).